# vue 3: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of ""

Tags: javascript, apache, vuejs3

Im trying to run simple vue3 application using options api. Here is code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
    }
  }

</script>


<div id="app">

</div>
<!---->
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'

   createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
    <script>
    export default {
        // Properties returned from data() become reactive state
        // and will be exposed on `this`.
        data() {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        },

        // Methods are functions that mutate state and trigger updates.
        // They can be bound as event listeners in templates.
        methods: {
            increment() {
                this.count++
            }
        },

        // Lifecycle hooks are called at different stages
        // of a component's lifecycle.
        // This function will be called when the component is mounted.
        mounted() {
            console.log(`The initial count is ${this.count}.`)
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="increment">Count is: {{ count }}</button>
</template>
```

But getting this error in browser (i tried to set in apache different mimetypes for vue: text/html, text/javascript, module):

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

note: if I dont use vue files and just write app code in main.js it works fine:

```
const app = createApp({
    // Properties returned from data() become reactive state
    // and will be exposed on `this`.
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },

    // Methods are functions that mutate state and trigger updates.
    // They can be bound as event listeners in templates.
    methods: {
        increment() {
            this.count++
        }
    },

    // Lifecycle hooks are called at different stages
    // of a component's lifecycle.
    // This function will be called when the component is mounted.
    mounted() {
        console.log(`The initial count is ${this.count}.`)
    }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

What am I doing wrong? would appreciate clarification for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: the error is in the mime type sent by the server, as stated in the error *the server responded with a MIME type of ""*

Comment: I know, could you clarify which mime type should be sent for vue files?

Comment: since in my experience, a bundled vue project never sends `.vue` file I have no idea ... I didn't think you used `.vue` files outside of some sort of "compiler" (or "bundler")

Comment: thx for tip, bundling works as a solution!